# xml-rpc parameter

Tags: java, xml, escaping, rpc

I'm using xml-rpc to create a java client that will connect to a xml-rpc server (Cisco 8710)
I would like that in my HTTP Post I can send the following:

```
<value><string>admin</string></value>

          params.add( Boolean.TRUE );
          params.add( new Integer (100) );
          params.add( "<string>admin</string>" );
```

Doing packet capture what is sent is the following:

```
&lt;string&gt;cisco&lt;/string&gt;
```

Using:
**org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClient;**

How can I escape the characters to be sent properly?

Thanks!

Comment: why not try `new String("admin")` ?

Comment: cause in xml-rpc that format is needed on Server

Comment: Ok, why don't you try to replace `<` with `&lt;` and `>` with `&gt;` and make the request, and see if it works? because I had a similar problem yesterday and solved it by sending encoded content. It got decoded on the server. Or, wait! Is it automatically encoded by your code?

Comment: I tried it and now I get: `&amp;lt;string&amp;gt;cisco&amp;lt;/string&amp;gt;`

Comment: how about trying `new String("<string>admin</string>")` ? Btw, if that doesn't work, I have no idea what the problem might be! Perhaps if you have access to server, why not decode content there?

Comment: Same issue, don't have access to server as code is fixed (Cisco code) but may try your first suggestion on new version of Cisco code. Found some escape library but not sure if xml-rpc is already modifying the parameter before sending it over the network. Thanks !

Comment: I believe params.add("admin"); will do the job